# Mautic is not processing the queue. Messages are in the spool/default folder

Tags: cron, spool, mautic

Mautic will not send my queued emails.

I have set up the cron jobs and they are running as expected. The cron job email report for the ":messages:send" cron job that runs every minute is always this...

Processing message queue
Messages sent: 0
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

I have messages in my queue, which I have sent via the Contacts Tab, by clicking on the contact name (myself) and then clicking on the Send Email button, just to send myself a test email.

In my configuration email settings I am using PHP Mail.

If I have the mail set to 'Send Immediately' it works fine. I get my test email instantly. But if I have it set to queue the message goes into my spool/default folder but when the cron job triggers it is not sent.

Things I have tried so far....

- I deleted the cache folder contents
- I checked to see if I have two versions of this file: SendChannelBroadcastCommand.php - I don't, I just have this file once, in the ChannelBundle/Command folder. It is not also in the CoreBundle/Command folder (as suggested by a similar post)
- I deleted all of the queued messages in the spool/default folder, then sent some more... which are now sitting in the folder just like before.

Things that might be a factor?

- The permissions for the file SendChannelBroadcastCommand.php is set to 644. I don't know if this is correct but assume it is.
- When I open the SendChannelBroadcastCommand.php file in dreamweaver, it flags it with lots of syntax errors. I don't really know enough about code to determine if these are genuine errors or if Dreamwaever is just being a little too sensitive. I also don't know if this file in included inside another one that'd make those errors disappear if Dreamweaver could see the complete end result, but I thought it was worth a mention.

Things that I'm sure are not a problem

- I'm certain that the cron job is set up correctly. It is running. And I receive the email reports (although I've turned those back off now as I don't want a report every minute)

I've seen this problem mentioned a few times on other forums but none of the solutions are working for me.

My Mautic installation is 2.14.0
My PHP is 7.0.31
Installation was via Softaculous on cPanel on a dedicated server hosted with Namecheap

Thank you in advance for any suggestions that I can try to fix this issue.

Steve.

Oh, in case you're wondering... I am using PHP Mail as Mautic would not connect to Amazon SES. For that I get the following error (which my hosting company was unable to help me fix, so I'm trying PHP mail)

Connection could not be established with host email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [Connection refused #111] Log data: ++ Starting Mautic\EmailBundle\Swiftmailer\Transport\AmazonTransport !! Connection could not be established with host email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [Connection refused #111] (code: 0)
++ Starting Mautic\EmailBundle\Swiftmailer\Transport\AmazonTransport !! Connection could not be established with host email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [Connection refused #111] (code: 0)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Amazon SES Connection refused #111] (code: 0) error, it is hard-coded in mautic to use port 2587 to connect to amazon ses, regardless of what port you put in the smtp port number. This is in Mautic 2.13.1 version. Make sure TCP 2587 in/out is open on your webserver firewall. This change solved that error message for me. Have not expierenced a queue error, sorry can't comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

**If your queue setup is perfect** then there is one more thing is there to setup in **cron level**.

That is `php /path/to/mautic/bin/console mautic:emails:send`

This command is used to **process queued emails** for Mautic

Check this for more info https://docs.mautic.org/en/setup/cron-jobs

Due to this only the emails are not processing, if your queue setup is good.
Just add the command and try again, it will work.